# insert into sql db a string that contain special character '

Tags: c#, sql, string

i want to insert to a sql table a string that might contain ' character.

what is my best way to do so ? 
should i insert a \ before the ' ? 
here's my command in a c# code:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(
    String.Format(
    "insert into ACTIVE.dbo.Workspaces_WsToRefile values({0},'{1}',getdate())", 
        folderId, 
        NewWorkspaceName), 
     myConnection);
```

where NewWorkspaceName might contain ' character, so the insert will cause an exception at the moment.

thanks in advanced, hadas.

Comment: You **should** use parameters in your query!

Comment: Beware of Little Bobby Tables!

Comment: What happens when NewWorkspaceName is `"hi');  DELETE FROM Users; --"` ?

Comment: i know for sure it won't be "hi'); DELETE FROM Users; --" , my only issue is with handeling ' on the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using SqlParameter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx

```
    string query = "insert into ACTIVE.dbo.Workspaces_WsToRefile values(@folderID, @newWorkSpace, @createDate)";

using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, SqlConnection))
{

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@folderID", folderId);
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have only one option, forget everything else. Use Parametrized queries like this

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into ACTIVE.dbo.Workspaces_WsToRefile" + 
                                      " values(@id, @space, getDate()", myConnection);  
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", folderId);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@space", NewWorkspaceName);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**folderID** and NewWorkspaceName, are passed to the Sql Engine inside parameters.
This will take care of special characters like quotes.
But you gain another benefit using parametrized queries. You avoid [Sql Injection Attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1):

```
NewWorkspaceName= NewWorkspaceName.Replace("\'","\'\'");
```

'' is a ' in sql

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string stringToDatabase=Server.HtmlEncode("կҤїАͻBsdҤїА");
```

This saves 'stringToDatabase' in your database
. Then while retreiving

```
string OriginalText=Server.HtmlDecode(stringFromDatabase);
```

Comment: It has to be WebUtility.HtmlEncode(stringFromDatabase) otherwise it does not work