# Session variable as a SqlParameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I've got this all except for my...

```
cmd.Parameters["@CAssetID"].Value.ToString();
```

Line of code where I am trying to assign the session variable to SqlParameter to pass it in to a stored procedure.  I just can't seem to get the syntax right. I've tried several different things here is my last attempt.

```
SqlConnection RejectConnecton = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GBAPTCCSR01;Initial Catalog=CInTracDB;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "usp_RejectSubmission";
cmd.Parameters["@CAssetID"].Value.ToString();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = RejectConnecton;

RejectConnecton.Open();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
RejectConnecton.Close();
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: you have not added ["@CAssetID"] to cmd. you should add it

Comment: What session variable? There's no session variable there. You're converting the value of a parameter (that isn't there) to a string and discarding it. What session variable?

Comment: This line does nothing: `cmd.Parameters["@CAssetID"].Value.ToString();` is that where you're trying to set the value?

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867729/insert-into-sql-db-a-string-that-contain-special-character/11867770#11867770

Comment: Change `cmd.Parameters["@CAssetID"].Value.ToString();` to `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CAssetID", Session["MySessionVar"]));` - may need a little tweaking based on your session variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAssetID", Session["YourSessionParamName"]);
```

Comment: The exact final code was:......cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAssetID",Session["CAssetID"]); Thanks to all for the responses and mybirthname nailing it.  I could have sworn I was there before but I must have had something crosseyed. Works perfect!