# Can't connect with database c#

Tags: c#

cmd.executenonquery showing (can't have null values) ERROR!

Here is the code behind

I am trying to insert data into textboxes and sent to a table in a database, but it keeps showing NULL.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=*******;Initial Catalog=MaleFemale;Integrated Security=True");

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into TableMaleFemale(Name,EiD,Gender) values ('" + NametextBox.Text + "', '" + EiDtextBox.Text + "', '" + GendertextBox.Text + "')", con);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, your code is wide open to SQL injection.  Which may very well be the source of the problem.  When the error happens, what is the *exact* query being executed by `cmd` (after you've inserted those values) and what is the *exact* error message?

Comment: What is SQL injection

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection  It basically means you're blindly executing any SQL code your users write into your application.  In .NET look into something called "parameterized queries".

Comment: OH. Okay.  It must be SQL injection?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867729/insert-into-sql-db-a-string-that-contain-special-character/11867770#11867770

Comment: Check you table definition for TableMaleFemale for any columns set to "NOT NULL". You may not be supplying enough columns in the insert statement.

Comment: @BrockRobichaux: It *might* be a SQL injection problem, since your code is SQL injectable.  The SQL injection is the root cause of your debugging problem though, mainly the fact that you *don't know* what SQL query you're actually executing.  So you're getting an error from SQL Server, based on code you're trying to execute on SQL Server, but you're not looking at what that code is.  *Step 1* is to at least examine what that code is.  It might not be what you *assume* it is.

Comment: you have to show real error messages, and where they occur. Not 'it keeps showing NULL'

Comment: most likely one of those Text fields is null. You cant do string + null

Comment: @pm100 yes you can.

Answer (score 2):

There are three things that you should change with your code:

1. Do not create one connection object and re-use it - connections are pooled by .NET, so creating them generally isn't en expensive process, plus you don't have to worry about checking the current state anymore.
2. Dispose of connections and commands immediately after you're done with them - this is convenient to do by using `using` statement blocks
3. Use parameters instead of concatenating SQL strings (expecially when dealing with user input) - using concatenation opens you up to SQL injection attacks and to characters that will foul up the SQL (e.g. an apostrophe in a name).  It also makes null values easier to deal with.

If I make those changes, your code is not more like this:

```
String connectionString = "Data Source=*******;Initial Catalog=MaleFemale;Integrated Security=True";

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string sql = "insert into TableMaleFemale(Name,EiD,Gender) values (@Name, @EiD, @Gender)"
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name").Value   = NametextBox.Text == null   ? DBNull.Value : NametextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EiD").Value    = EiDtextBox.Text == null    ? DBNull.Value : EiDtextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender").Value = GendertextBox.Text == null ? DBNull.Value : GendertextBox.Text;
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

None of these three things may fix your stated problem, but it will solve *other* problems that you don't have yet.

Comment: for solving problems OP doesnt have yet

Comment: apparently i cant say `+1` anymore, but thats what I intended to say